# Modify only a specific tuple in python (incomprehensible)

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of 10,000 tuples.
Each tuple has 31 entries.
Let's say I just want to modify only the first entry of the 77th tuple.

```
empty_tuple=[0] * 31
lst=[empty_tuple] * 10000
lst[77][0]='salut'
```

It does work but all the first entries of all the 10,000 tuples are now the same.
What's going on here?

```
print lst[1987][0]
'salut'
```

Comment: It looks like you're creating lists, not tuples. Tuples are immutable, you can't modify them. You are creating a copy of the *same* object in every list element. Modifying it modifies all copies. You need a deep copy. [Check out this tutorial.](http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php)

Comment: Your `lst` contains 10,000 references to the same list. Try with `lst = [empty_tuple[:] for _ in range(10000)]`

Comment: Yeah sorry it's a list of lists

Comment: Ok Thank you Andrea. Why is there a '_' in lst = [empty_tuple[:] for _ in range(10000)] ? Is it a typo?

Comment: @hansglick: `_` is conventionally the name for unused variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list of lists, changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[empty_tuple] * 10000` creates a list that contains 10000 references to `empty_tuple`, so when you modify it with `lst[77][0]=...`, it will be reflected across all of `l`.

It's a bit tricky if you really want to use tuples, as they are immutable, but you can do something like:

```
>>> sett = lambda t, idx, val: tuple((v if i != idx else val) for i,v in enumerate(t))
>>> l = [(0,) * 3] * 4
>>> l
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]
>>> l[1] = sett(l[1], 2, 42)
>>> l
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 42), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]
```

where `sett` is a function that takes a tuple `t`, an index `idx`, and a value `val`, and returns a tuple that is identical to `t` in every index but `idx`, where it contains `val`.

One way to set up a list of distinct lists would be:

```
>>> l = map(lambda _: [0] * 3, xrange(4))
>>> l[0][1] = 2
>>> l
[[0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: `tuple([0] * 3)` = `(0,) * 3`

Comment: Ok Thanks Vad but let's I don't want to create 10,000 references but rather a simply a list of 10,000 lists full of zeros. How would you do that?

Comment: I've added a snippet.

Comment: Ok @Vlad thanks! I don't think I need references but again thank you.

Comment: I don't know if you can store them any other way, not without a different type of data structure.